# access to particles's property of CCParticleSystemQuad in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am very new to cocos2d and ios development. I am creating animation using particle system.I have implemented one particle system using CCParticleSystemQuad class of particle system class. i want to access all properties of particles like position ,direction,speed and all . I used that property but what i want to make that is not achieved by that particle system .I want to move particles in specific direction that is my custom direction. So that when i run that particle system that will run only in custom direction.I have created particle system like this ...

```
self->emitter =[CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"stars.plist"];
emitter.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"sprite.png"];
self->emitter.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self->emitter setScale:1];
[self addChild:self->emitter];
```

My question is how to give custom direction to particles. No. of particles in the system is fixed.

Any kind of help will be appreciated . i want to move my all particles from center to all directions and i also want to scale them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale particles, you can use startSize, startSizeVar, endSize and endSizeVar properties of ParticleSystem.

ParticleSystem also have many parameters that you can set to move particles, like angle, radial acceleration, emmiterMode (you can try the cocos2d tests to see some examples of particles).

But if you and a new custom movement that can't be set on these parameters, then you`ll need to subclass CCParticleSystemQuad and override update or updateQuadWithParticle methods (It will be complex).

Comment: This works fine. scaling particles using these properties >> startSize, startSizeVar, endSize and endSizeVar.

Comment: And could you achieve the custom movements? If so, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @Mauricino Tollin . i achieved custom movement too .. i have created one plist file & used it with my particle system .it works with rich set of properties .